# Remove duplicate values from the column of a PostgreSQL table and maintain only one value per column for duplicated rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to format the data of below table as follows. Here on the value column, I want to maintain only on value for each of the duplicated rows.

input table

```
code    value
A       10
A       10
A       10
B       20
B       20
B       20
C       30
C       30
D       40
```

Expected result

```
code    value
A        10
A   
A   
B        20
B   
B   
C        30
C   
D        40
```

Comment: you would like to have `null` instead of value? what have you tried?

Comment: Yes null or zero is good for me

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql?

Comment: Am using Postgres

Comment: Do you want to update the table, or just get these values on output?

Comment: @Nick only I need to get this as an output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A combination of `CASE` and window function can solve your problem

```
select code, 
       case when t.rn = 1 then value else null end value
from (
    select row_number() over (partition by code, value order by value) rn,
           code, value
    from your_table
) t
```